# videoview wont play video

Tags: android

Hello trying to get a video to play when you press a button, but when i start the app i get the message the video wont play.

```
    import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.VideoView;

public class lydbrett extends AppCompatActivity {

    VideoView videolyd;
    Uri uri;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lydbrett);

        videolyd = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.videoView);

        uri = Uri.parse("android.resource;//" + getPackageName()+ "/" + R.raw.nice);
        videolyd.setVideoURI(uri);
        Button playButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        playButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                videolyd.start();

            }
        });
```

Comment: You want to play a video from your project assets ??

Comment: yes from my raw folder, the name of the video is "nice"

Comment: android.resource: not ;

Comment: https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B5ml5B_CYAE3XCX.jpg

Comment: did it works ??

Comment: yupp! thanks for the help

Comment: i dont know how to do that.